# Detecting value has returned to below threshold before allowing value change

Tags: python, algorithm, logic

I'm trying to design is a system that takes user input (from a continuously variable analogue potentiometer 0-100) and uses that input to set a value and I'm looking for a good method to handle a failure case.

I need to handle an error in the system that once detected sets the value to zero and requires the input to be brought back to a low value below a threshold before the user can again increase the value as required. I would also be fine for the value to return to zero if it allowed for simpler logic.

This seems like quite a common piece software safety logic however I have struggled to find any information about this problem on the internet. (I was thinking it might share some logic with a Schmitt trigger?)

If you have ideas about this problem or know of its name/ a good set of resources that would be much appreciated.

I have developed a simple python program as an example to perform this however I'm sure that is not the most robust or efficient method to solve this problem.

```
# check value has returned to below 5% before allowing
# increase after failure case
value = 0
user_command = 0
failure_case = True

while True:
    ## get input
    raw_input = input()
    if (raw_input == 'e'):
        # if input is 'e'
        # enter failure case
        failure_case = True
    else:
        try:
            # if input is a number 
            user_command = int(raw_input)
        except:
            pass

    if (failure_case):
        # a failure has been detected
        print("Waiting for value to return to below 5")
        # set value to zero
        value = 0

        # only remove the error flag once the
        # input value is below 5
        if (user_command < 5):
            failure_case = False
    else:
        # no error thus set value to the user input
        value = user_command
    # print the accepted value
    print(value);
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You could investigate state machines or the state pattern. It seems like you need two states: normal state, but an error input moves to the error state and error state which waits for a zero input.

Comment: I agree, it does seem like a problem suited to state machines. In this case its got two states which are stored in the `failure_case` bool when in the non failure-state state the value follows the user input and when in the failure state the value equals zero and to move between the two states there is an arbitrary failure trigger to enter the error and a conditional check to change back to the normal state.